Flexible width in HTML table
I would like my table to fulfill these properties:

The width of the table is 100% of the parent container.
All columns width are fit to the maximum column width.
The column flex-column takes the remaining space.


In the figure, the middle column takes, the remaining horizontal space while the other columns width are fitted to their content.
I played with Flexbox and CSS Grid, but I couldn't get any result yet. What is the proper method?


table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th.flex-column,
td.flex-column {
  width: auto;
}

th:not(.flex-column),
td:not(.flex-column) {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th class="flex-column">B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">foo</td>
      <td class="flex-column">2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex-column">4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex-column">6</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Perhaps update the snippet with the CSS you tried so we can assist in fixing it

Please check the tds that you have noted as 'flex-column' - they are in fact not all in the same column (2 is in column B not column C).

@AHaworth You are right :)

@MarkSchultheiss I've updated with what I tried so far.

What do you mean by "the remaining space"? If columns (no matter how many) are set to the maximum width, there won't be any remaining space. Only one column could use all the width.

Perhaps provide a visual of the desired results

@kzi Indeed, only one column is allowed to be a flex-column

by "fit to the maximum column width." did you mean to say perhaps "maximum width size of content in the column?"

just as a reminder: html table are at first flexible about width (and height)  table-layout:fixed; kills it.  Beside width:0 on cell will shrink it down as much the content can let it shrink as long as table-layout is not set to fixed. Also tables comes with colgroup/col tags, to make it easy to size and colorize columns. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rNEOvLB  this comment to complete @johannes 's answer :)

Remove the table-layout: fixed, use a very small fixed value for the side colums, and possibly also use white-space: nowrap; on them if you want their content not to be wrapped. The width will not remain at that fixed value, but adapt if needed.


table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th.flex-column,
td.flex-column {
  text-align: left;
}

th:not(.flex-column),
td:not(.flex-column) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 6px;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th class="flex-column">B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">foo</td>
      <td class="flex-column">2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex-column">4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex-column">6</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Here you fixed the column to 8px, but the B column should take the remaining space. Changing td.flex-column to auto doesn't work :(

@nowox note that I completely changed my answer (I initially misunderstood your question, your image of the desired result made it clearer)

Making the flex column width 100% will work.
This snippet wraps the table in a div to demonstrate that the table can pick up the width of the parent.


.container {
  width: 50vw;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: auto;
}

th.flex-column,
td.flex-column {
  width: 100%;
}

th:not(.flex-column),
td:not(.flex-column) {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

</div>
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th class="flex-column">B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">foo</td>
        <td class="flex-column">2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="flex-column">4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="flex-column">6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>






body {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  text-align: start;
}

th.flex-column,
td.flex-column {
  width: 100%;
}

th:not(.flex-column),
td:not(.flex-column) {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th class="flex-column">B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">foo</td>
      <td class="flex-column">2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex-column">4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="flex-column">6</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



You mentioned grid so here is an example of that.
I added a wrapper just for convenience in the CSS but it could be a class on the table as well.  Note how I used the grid rows on the foo and put it at the top of the block also.


body {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
}

/* make these rows all apear to be direct children of table element */
.wrapper thead,
.wrapper thead>tr,
.wrapper tbody,
.wrapper tbody>tr,
.wrapper tfoot,
.wrapper tfoot>tr {
  display: contents;
}

table {
  border: solid #d000d0 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  justify-content: start;
  text-align: left;
}

.rowspan3 {
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
}

.wrapper th,
.wrapper td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: minmax( min-content, 1fr);
}

.wrapper .flex-column,
.wrapper .flex-column {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.wrapper th:not(.flex-column),
.wrapper td:not(.flex-column) {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th class="flex-column">B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="rowspan3">foo</td>
        <td class="flex-column">2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="flex-column">4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="flex-column">6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




Not sure if your image related to the foo being at the top of that block is important, but here is is centered on the rowspan=3 there; couple ways to handle that IF that is important.
